# Images not displayed when moving site to local

Tags: images, localhost, local-installation

I set up a local environment to customize a friend's WP blog. However almost none of the images are being displayed.

The remote site's URL is `http://sitename.com` and my local virtual host is `http://sitename.dev`.

I have found a couple different cases when the images are not displayed:

- The src URL looks like this: `http://i1.wp.com/sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/xxxxxx` and opening this link on the browser shows the image correctly. However there's a `srcset` attribute with the URL `http://i1.wp.com/sitename.dev/wp-content/uploads/xxxxxx` and that causes a 504 HTML error because obviously there is no `http://i1.wp.com/sitename.dev`.
- The other case just has a src URL like the previous `srcset`, it looks like `http://i1.wp.com/sitename.dev/wp-content/uploads/xxxxxx` so it is unable to load the resource.

So it looks like the main problem is that `i1.wp.com` that is being prepended to my local URL and it's completely messing with the routes.

When editing posts from wp-admin all images are shown correctly. Well the featured image preview isn't displayed correcly because it tried prepending `i1.wp.com` again but when selecting the image from the gallery it is displayed correcty (and the URL is `http://sitename.dev/xxxxx`).

I have no idea where that prepended segment comes from but I would like to know how to either get rid of it or how to set up images correctly in my local environment.

Comment: Check this out :  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/310488/132953

Answer (score 0):

Well images are basically stored "wp_posts". Links of each image are stored in "guid" column of the table.

try this in your DB

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`guid` ASC
```

So the problem is clear - the links doesnt match.
To get rid of the problem simply manually reselect each image from your current setup. Thats it.

Comment: What exactly should I change there? I forgot to include that in my question but I had already checked `wp_posts` and it looks fine (most links refer to the `sitename.dom` rather than the `sitename.dev` but that's ok because these resources are supposed to be accessible, and they are because I can open the picture links with the browser). The problem is that prepended chunk `i1.wp.com` that I don't know where it's coming from and it is certainly not in the database (in the table `wp_posts`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Photon Jetpack feature. I just had to disable it. Although I consider this to be a dirty patch, and not a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

use a plugin to replace all links from the dev site to match the links with the new domain.

You can also use wp-cli as well.

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Answer (score 0):

You need to update all the links in the database. Depending on the size of the website, this can be difficult. I move sites over regularly. The best thing to do is - without playing around with the database yourself is to use the 'Velvet Blues Update URLs'. It's basically a string and replace which replaces the old links to the new one with a simple UI.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/