# Updated Site URL but it is not reflecting the changes

Tags: site-url

I have my Wordpress installation located in "webroot/example.com/WP" folder.

Currently, http://example.com shows a 404 page not found error.

However, http://example.com/WP loads the Wordpress site. In the

Settings->General area, I have both Wordpress URL and Site URL set to http://example.com/WP

Now, I would like to change only the Site URL to http://example.com so that that is the URL that people enter to visit the site.

I tried logging into phpMyAdmin and editing the 'home' field to http://example.com

However, the result is the same.

I followed the instructions given in the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) but to no avail.

Comment: try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310466/wordpress-white-page-with-certain-database/310488?noredirect=1#comment459068_310488

Answer (score 0):

Now move your files and folders outside of the WP folder.

It's possible to use .htaccess rewrite rules "trick" the browsers though, but if your not familiar with how to do that, I recommend not doing so.

Comment: I'm on Windows hosting. Some solutions I have read suggest that I place the index.html file in the example.com folder and modify it. Would I still need .htaccess?