# Replace "http://localhost:8888/" by website URL in Wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, localhost, site-url

Due to some recent security breach, I had to replace my website on the server with all the new local files.

**Question**: Now I see "**`http://localhost:8888/`**" string in my blog posts ( e.g. image sources and everywhere else) due to which the website is not working properly.

I have already generated fresh permalinks `Settings->Permanlinks->Save`

How can I replace "**`http://localhost:8888/`**" with "**`mysiteurl.com`**". Is there any script?

Comment: You could use a plugin like [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/).

Comment: following this might help you
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310466/wordpress-white-page-with-certain-database/310488?noredirect=1#comment459068_310488

Comment: @user141080 I used Better Search Replace. It did the job of replacing all the strings in the database (still some pages didn't work, but that was some different problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fix the URLs in the database. Although you can do it with MySQL commands, the easiest way I've found is with the "Better Search and Replace" plugin. Easy to use, and works.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Of course, backup your database first. But it works quite well.